# Options to init with @MainActor property as default value

Tags: swift, concurrency

I have a class which up until now used the `UIApplication.shared` as a default argument during it's initialisation. The simplified version of it:

```
final class MyClass {
    private var application: UIApplication
    
    init(application: UIApplication = UIApplication.shared) {
        self.application = application
    }
}
```

With `Strict Concurrency Checking` using the `Complete` option now gives the following error:

> Main actor-isolated class property 'shared' can not be referenced
> from a non-isolated context

It makes sense since `UIApplication` is marked as `@MainActor` hence, all it's properties are async:

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
@MainActor open class UIApplication : UIResponder {
open class var shared: UIApplication { get }

...
}
```

I see two solutions for this:

**#Solution1**

Mark the property as optional and initialise it during the `init`. In some cases it may seem as a good idea, but with this we loose the ability to dependency inject the property and make it testable. Also using optionals further when we know the property is indeed initialised is uncomfortable:

```
final class MyClass {
    private var application: UIApplication?
    
    @MainActor
    init() {
        self.application = UIApplication.shared
    }
}
```

**#Solution2**

Let's make the caller responsible for initialising the class on the `@Mainactor`:

```
final class MyClass {
    private var application: UIApplication
    
    init(application: UIApplication) {
        self.application = application
    }
    
    // Just to present what the caller would do
    @MainActor
    func option1ToInit() {
       _ = MyClass(application: UIApplication.shared)
    }
    
    // Just to present what the caller would do
    func option2ToInit() {
        Task {
            _ = await MyClass(application: UIApplication.shared)
        }
    }
}
```

The second solution seems to work nicely, however I need to do a bit of refactor work so all the callers are executing on the `@MainActor`. I was wondering if there is any other option I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add `@MainActor` to init (which it seems you can from your description), then you just need to move the accessing of `.shared` into the init:

```
@MainActor
init(application: UIApplication? = nil) {
    self.application = application ?? .shared
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works as expected

Comment: I don't see any other practical way to even instantiate a MainActor most of the time, and yet you never see this documented.